# Compile error for D program file in windows

Tags: windows, command-prompt, d, dmd

I have just installed **`D programming language`**(dmd installer) and wrote a small program *`helloworld.d`* , but when I run in my windows in command promote using this command:

```
C:/D>dmd helloworld.d
```

it is giving error saying: *`"dmd is not recognized as an internal or external command"`*. Can anyone tell me what is the problem?

Comment: [**common...**](https://www.google.fr/search?client=opera&q=is+not+recognized+as+an+internal+or+external+command&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8), flaged as off-topic

Comment: Sahil, the directory where DMD exe file is located is not in the path. Once you put it in the path you will be able to execute successfully `dmd helloworld.d`.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to open the command prompt via the `D2 32-bit Command Prompt` shortcut, which is placed in your Start Menu during installation. This will open a command prompt with the environment set up so you can invoke `dmd` as in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to specify the full path to where you placed the `dmd` compiler:

```
"c:\Some_Folder\dmd.exe" helloworld.d
```

or add it to the `PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need download installer, but not zip package.